# Do I need a separate VkFrameBuffer for each swap chain image?

Tags: c++, vulkan, framebuffer

I am trying to learn Vulkan, but I am confused about whether i need a separate e frame buffer for every swap chain image for all of my render passes. I understand that I need as many frame buffers as swap chain images for the render pass that renders to the swap chain. But is this the case for all of my render passes? If I am understanding thing properly, there can be multiple frames being worked on at the same time, so to prevent one frame from overriding a image that another frame is still reading from, I should have separate VkImages and VkFramebuffers for each swap chain image, right?

I have no idea if this is the case or if I’m am misunderstanding how the vulkan api works.

I am also wondering if I need separate descriptor sets for each swap chain image since I watched a tutorial where that was the case.

Are there any good tutorial online that explain stuff like this that I can follow?

Comment: "*But is this the case for all of my render passes?*" So, these would be render passes not using a swap chain, right? So what do you mean by this: "*I should have separate VkImages and VkFramebuffers for each swap chain image, right?*"